# Error message shown above input field with Parsley.JS and select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, parsley.js

Without select2 js dropdown the messages coming below the dropdownlist but after using select2 js error messages coming above it.

Can I show error message below the select2 js dropdownlist or in any specific position.

working code would help!

[image: Getting error message are above my input fields :(]

[image: Getting error message are above my input fields :( Ex2]

Comment: Maybe a CSS rule would do the trick, or else look into adding your own error container and specifying it with `data-parsley-errors-container`

Comment: data-parsley-errors-container="#id" works thanks @Marc-AndréLafortune

Answer (score 0):

### Pure ParsleyJS

Consider using custom validator like this:

```
Parsley.addValidator('allselected',
    function (value) {
        return true==(value != '-1')
    });


<select data-parsley-allselected="true" >
    <option value="-1">Please select value</option>
    <option value="1">Text1</option>
    <option value="2">Text2</option>
</select>
```

the error message will be presented **below** the select input.

please note that you must add to your language locale a proper `allselected` message.